Modify cart total and then order total when an order is placed in WooCommerce
I'm using this code to modify my total on the checkout page
However, if I place an order, the modified total is not reflected in the order itself, and still has the unmodified checkout total.
Can someone help with what step I am missing, please?
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'mod_cart_total' );
function mod_cart_total() {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
            return;
WC()->cart->total = 123.45; //modified checkout total which works on the checkout page but not anywhere else
}

I assumed setting the modified total would be reflected when the order is placed/saved

Sounds like assigning to WC()->cart->total only modifies the current object instance for the script runtime, but doesn't actually write through into the session. Can you explain what you actually want to achieve here? Because just arbitrarily assigning a different value for the total, doesn't sound like it would make all that much sense. If you wanted to add any custom fees, or the other direction, apply some discount, there is proper ways to do that.

I have a minor plugin conflict. Shipping rules vs multiple shipping addresses. Shipping is being multiplied by the number of unique addresses so I've simply divided the cart total by the number of addresses to give me the correct total. That works but when the order is placed the order total is the unmodified total (total x no# of addresses)
